# I need help choosing a statistical method for my problem

Tags: calibration, repeatability

I have 12 tools from different labs that are similar to each other. They measure two different parameters (green intensity and red intensity).

I have 4 samples that will be measured 3 times each by each tool. So in the end I will have
12 × 4 × 3 × 2 results.

If I had only one parameter, I would use a Gage R&R cross analysis. But since I have 2 different responses, what method suits the best of this type of problem?

Comment: Is the objective to assess how calibrated the 12 tools are?

Comment: yes,  to evaluate the performance of the tools. To evaluate the variation due to repeatability or reproducibility and if there is any relation between the two parameters.